# What is the proper implementation of the back button press in same activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, touch, logic

I want to detect the back button. 
However my current implementation does not even detect the back button.

CODE:

```
   @Override
    public boolean onTouch(MotionEvent e, int scaledX, int scaledY) {

        //... OTHER CODE ...
        else if(e.getAction() == MotionEvent.BUTTON_BACK){
            System.out.println("BACK BUTTON PRESSED");
            setCurrentState(new MenuState());
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: show different state ? what extactly that means

Comment: You can override `onBackPressed` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29.

Comment: @Diva  go from my current view to a different view

Comment: ok but both arein same or different activiies? @jssmkp

Comment: there in the same @Diva

Comment: ok you have to basicall dismiss via code , can u plz show both custom view in code?

Comment: what do you mean by "it will show a different state" ? why cant you override 'onBackPressed' ?

Comment: @Diva all I want to know is why  MotionEvent.BUTTON_BACK isn't being detected once my back button is pressed.

Comment: i am not sure if motion event detects button clicks of phone

Comment: try `invalidate();  return super.onTouchEvent(event);` at the end of ur method @jssmkp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `onBackPressed()` inside your Activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's written in the documentation:

> public static final int BUTTON_BACK
>   Button constant: Back button pressed **(mouse back button)**. The system may send a KEYCODE_BACK key press to the application when this button is pressed.

You need to override `onKeyUp` function from the Activity (not from the View):

```
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) 
    {
        //todo
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Intent inside `onBackPressed()`like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() 
    {
    Intent BackIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(BackIntent);
    finish();
    }
```